# delete characters in a string from begining to ']' character

Tags: python, string, character

Delete characters upto and including ']'

```
a="[12] hi how are you [1]" 
b="[13][14] hello"
```

expected output :

```
a="hi how are you [1]"

b=" hello"
```

Comment: Did you mean: `a = ' '.join(a.split()[1:])`?

Comment: you can use `rindex()` to find the right-most index of a character. Then you can slice with that. For example: `a[a.rindex(']')+1:].strip()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expression to achieve this

```
import re

txt = "[12] hi how are you" 
x = re.sub("\[[0-9]+\]\s*", "", txt)
print(x)
```

Comment: it worked. x = re.sub("\[[0-9]+\]\s?", "", txt) can you clarify

Comment: The sub function replaces matching text pattern with specified replacement.
In regex, angle brackets have special meaning. In order match angle brackets, I needed to escape them with a trailing slash `\[` ` \]` in the pattern 
[0-9] matches any number the `+` allows match any number.
`\s` matches space. `*` makes the space optional. So it will match zero or more spaces.

Comment: if the input is " [1] his roll no is [1234]" i'm expecting output as " his roll no is [1234]" but its deleting everything in [ ] and result is " his roll no is "

Comment: You can use the third parameter to limit replacement: x = re.sub("\[[0-9]+\]\s*", "", txt, 1)

Comment: using this  x = re.sub("[[0-9]+]\s*", "", txt, 1),  dont work for b="[13][14] hello"

Comment: res = None
for i in range(len(txt)):
 temp = re.search(r'[a-z]', txt[i], re.I)
 if temp is not None:
    res = temp.start()
    tx[i]=txt[i][res:]
print(tx)

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `rindex()`:

```py
def doIt(a):
    if "]" in a:
        x = a.rindex("]")
        a = a[x + 1 :].strip()
    return a
```

Lets Test it:

```py
a = "[12] hi how are you"
b = "[13][14] hello"
c = "kahbscdkashju asjhd bkaisd b dab bui"
print(doIt(a))
print(doIt(b))
print(doIt(c))
```

Output:

```py
hi how are you
hello
kahbscdkashju asjhd bkaisd b dab bui
```

---

You can also write custom method without using any built-in string method.

```py
def doIt(a):
    ans = []
    for i in range(len(a) - 1, -1, -1):
        if a[i] == "]":
            break
        ans.insert(0, a[i])
    return "".join(ans).strip()
```

Comment: if the input is " [1] his roll no is [1234]" i'm expecting output as " his roll no is [1234]" but its deleting everything before ']' and result is "   "